# 'LOWER' function for ogr2ogr?

Tags: gdal, sql, ogr2ogr

As part of an ogr2ogr operation, I would like to select a string property in its lowercase form.

Sample geojson:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "name": "sample",
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
        }
    },
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "sampleField1": "UPPERCASE"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [8.1, 50.5],
                    [8.2, 50.5],
                    [8.2, 50.6],
                    [8.1, 50.6],
                    [8.1, 50.5]
                ]
            ]
        }
    }]
}
```

LOWER does not seem to be supported as part of ogr2ogr as I have tried the following command which fails with the error message `ERROR 1: Undefined function 'LOWER' used.`.

```
ogr2ogr -sql "SELECT LOWER(sampleField1) FROM sample" -f "GeoJSON" <FILEPATH>/sample-output.geojson <FILEPATH>/sample.geojson
```

Comment: OGR SQL has very few functions, and case changing isn't one of them that I can see. Maybe you could use a JSON processor (like `jq`) to run through the GeoJSON and do the conversion, then feed that to `ogr2ogr`. I'm no `jq` expert though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the "LOWER" function if you change the [SQL dialect](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html#cmdoption-ogr2ogr-dialect) to "SQLITE".

```sql
ogr2ogr -dialect SQLITE -sql "SELECT geometry,LOWER(sampleField1) as sampleField1 FROM sample" -f "GeoJSON" <FILEPATH>/sample-output.geojson <FILEPATH>/sample.geojson
```

Comment: Oooh simpler than my idea (so I've deleted)! I thought the dialect was intimately tied to the output format because it was in the driver, but I see now! You might want to select that `AS sampleField1` and also select the geometry to get a spatial output.

Comment: @Spacedman you are totally correct with your suggestion... I only copied the command line from the question and didn't look at the SQL query... changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the geometry selection..